# C++ - Is a class prototype necessary ?

Tags: c++, class, prototype

Note : Code is posted below.

I want class `dynamic array` to be able to instantiate the `merge_inner` class.  So I added a public function like this:

```
merge_sort()  // merge_sort() is function in class dynamic_array
  {
  merge_inner<T> M1;
  }
```

However this is in one file and merge_inner is defined below dynamic_array.  How do I create a class prototype so that dynamic array know that merge_inner is a real class.

The error given is.

```
merge_inner not declared in scope
```

Thanks

```
#include "c_include.cpp"

using namespace std;

template <class T> class dynamic_array
  {
  protected:
    T* array;
  public:
    int size;
    void rorder();
    void order();
    void randorder();
    void print_operator(ostream&)const;
    dynamic_array(int sizein)
      {
      size=sizein;
      array=new T[size]();
      }
    merge_sort()
      {
      merge_inner<T> M1;
      }
  };

template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::print_operator(ostream &os=cout)const
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) os << array[i] << endl;
  }

template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::randorder()
  {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int *ap;
  for(ap=array;ap!=array+size;++ap){*ap=rand();} 
  }

template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::order()
  {
  int *ap,i=0;
  for(ap=array;ap!=array+size;++ap)                                             
    { 
    *ap=i;
    ++i;        
    } 
  }

template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::rorder()
  {
  int *ap,i=size-1;
  for(ap=array;ap!=array+size;++ap)                                             
    { 
    *ap=i;
    --i;        
    } 
  }

template<class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, dynamic_array<T> const& data) 
  { 
  data.print_operator(stream);
  return stream; 
  }   

/*
Merge Sort
*/

template <class T> class merge_inner : public dynamic_array <T>
  {
  using dynamic_array<T>::array;
  private:
    const static int size;
    int scratch[];
    void flip_if_unordered(int &x, int &y)
      {
      if(array[x]>array[y])
        {
        int tmp=array[x];
        array[x]=array[y];
        array[y]=tmp;
        }
      }
    void merge_algo(int &left, int &right_begin, int &right)
      {
      int iter,iter_left=left,iter_right=right_begin;  
      for(iter=left;iter<=right;++iter)
        {
        if( (iter_right>right) || ((iter_left < right_begin) && (array[iter_left]<=array[iter_right])))
          {
          scratch[iter]=array[iter_left];
          ++iter_left;
          }
        else
          {
          scratch[iter]=array[iter_right];
          ++iter_right;
          }
        }
      for(iter=left;iter<=right;++iter){array[iter]=scratch[iter];}
      }
    void merge_recurse(int left,int right)
      {
      int left_end=(left+((right-left)/2)); 
      int right_begin=left_end+1;  
      if(((left+1)==right)){flip_if_unordered(left,right);return;}
      else if ((left==right)){return;}
      else
        { 
        merge_recurse(left,left_end);               
        merge_recurse(right_begin,right);  
        merge_algo(left,right_begin,right);
        }   
      }
  public:
    merge_inner()
      {
      scratch = new T[size]();
      if(scratch != NULL){merge_recurse(0, size);}
      }
  };

/*Quick Sort

    void quick_sort()
      {
      quick_recurse(0,size);
      }
    void quick_recurse(int left, int right) 
      {  
      int l = left, r = right, tmp;
      int pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];
      while (l <= r)
        {
        while (array[l] < pivot)l++;
        while (array[r] > pivot)r--;
        if (l <= r) 
          {
          tmp = array[l];
          array[l] = array[r];
          array[r] = tmp;
          l++;
          r--;
          }
        }
      if (left < r)quick_recurse(left, r);
      if (l < right)quick_recurse(l, right);
      }  
*/
```

Comment: Surely, this isn't real code: `merge_sort` doesn't have return type, the code includes a .cpp file, and -- most importantly -- nobody indents their code like that!

Comment: Is `merge_sort` supposed to be a constructor, because it doesn't match the name of the class in which it is being defined? If it's just a member function, it needs a return type.

Comment: no merge_sort is not a constructor..it is the public interface used to instantiate merge_inner which is a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a forward declaration of `merge_inner` template before you define `dynamic array`:

```
template <typename> class merge_inner;
```

Note that this suffices and you can declare `merge_inner<T> M1;` even though the template hasn't been defined yet. This is because `dynamic_array` is itself a template, and the complete type `merge_inner<T>` is only required when the outer template is itself instantiated.

Comment: Awesome...I added a template to my dynamic_array so it could use ints, floats, etc...and now the syntax has increase everywhere...I have to make my derrived class use template..and I have to put it the forward delcaration fo the derrived class...it is everywhere

Comment: You could always submit your class to SE/codereview. Personally I'd suggest you use an allocator, like `vector`, rather than the array-`new`.

Comment: Soon...I'm hoping my dynamic array class will be a more efficient vector...that it will have a subset of Vector's functions

Answer (score 2):

Just separate your declaration and your implementation.

In your `dynamic_array`, have this code:

```
// Declare, but don't implement yet
dynamic_array(int sizein);
merge_sort();
```

Then further down in your file, after you have declared `merge_inner`, put the implementation of the previously-declared functions:

```
dynamic_array::dynamic_array(int sizein)
{
  size=sizein;
  array=new T[size]();
}
dynamic_array::merge_sort()
{
  merge_inner<T> M1;
}
```

They could even be in a separate file that gets #included at the end of your file.
That way, your interface is easy to read, and your implementation is separated out.

Comment: dynamic_array is a class....merge_sort is a function...Are you sure..mmm...I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @ChrisAaker: You don't have to have your implementation coded inline in a class, whether it's templated or not. Think of how 'normal' classes are done in C++ - with a .h and a .cpp. In this case, you're just putting the .cpp portion directly after the declaration in the same file.

Comment: of course...I get tired of having too many files open...so I put them together...this is probably not "best practice"